# .destroy() doesnt work killing application

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm displaying two windows. The first one for saving my game with Entry widget. And the second one which is my game.

When I close the widget with `.destroy()` function it works. But then as I want to leave the game I do `fenetre.destroy()` but nothing happens. And I got a message error when I close the window manually:

```
    _tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "destroy" command: application has been destroyed
```

This is my code:

```
def game_quit():
    global name
    if askyesno("Quit game ?","Are you sure? :("):
        if askyesno("Save ?","Do you want to save your game? "):
            ask_name()
            save_scoreG(grid,lenght)
    fenetre.destroy()



    def ask_name():
        global entry, master
        master = Toplevel()
        master.title("Your Name")
        button=Button(master, text='Input your name and click here', command = get_name, bg= "yellow" )
        usertext= StringVar()
        entry = Entry(master, textvariable=usertext)
        entry.pack()
        button.pack()
        master.mainloop()


    def get_name():
        global  name, entry, master
        name = str(entry.get())
        master.destroy()


    def save_scoreG(grid,lenght):
        global name 

        with open('score','a') as s:
           s.write(str(lenght)+':' + name +':'+ str(score(grid,lenght))+'\n')
```

I can't simplify this to get the error in shell:

```
>>> from tkinter import Toplevel, Tk
>>> fenetre = Tk()
>>> w = Toplevel()
>>> w.destroy()
>>> fenetre.destroy()

>>> fenetre.destroy()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Z:\py34-64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1842, in destroy
    self.tk.call('destroy', self._w)
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "destroy" command: application has been destroyed
```

Comment: Have you tried returning the function then assigning the callback?

Comment: You have to give us actual code that runs and replicates the problem. You can only get the error if you try to destroy a window twice, so the conclusion is, that's exactly what you're doing. When I run the same commands as you in the second example, I don't get the error you say you do.

Comment: Are you calling `mainloop` more than once? It looks rather suspicious to be calling it in `ask_name`.

Comment: https://github.com/sdescamp/20488 Here's my projet, open graphical_2048.py and run it. To get the error, go in Game > quit > Yes > Yes > enter any name and click. The application doesn't quit and if you manualy leave an error appears.

Comment: I solved my problem. Just replaced master.destroy() by master.quit()

Comment: Did you mean "I can simplify this" rather than "can't"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not a fan of using `global` variables, especially in a GUI program, where everything should be in classes inheriting from the base widgets.

I would like to propose a function that will do what I think you are trying to achieve, in -in my opinion- a much clearer way.

So here is a function that opens a pop-up, asks a name, and returns it.

```
def ask_name():
    toplevel = tk.Toplevel()
    label = tk.Label(toplevel, text="What's your name?")
    entry = tk.Entry(toplevel)
    button = tk.Button(toplevel, text="OK", command=toplevel.quit)

    toplevel.pack(label)
    toplevel.pack(entry)
    toplevel.pack(button)

    toplevel.mainloop()

    return entry.get()
```

This function allows you not to use `global` variables. Besides, it takes no parameter. I like this style, because this function could almost be integrated into a `utils.py` module, since it is absolutely independent of any context.

Though this might not directly solve your problem, this philosophy of avoiding `global` variables will help keep your code clean of weird dependencies, and much easier to understand and debug.